# Remove and store elements from a sorted array into different array of objects Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

I am receiving an array of 15 objects named `arrayReceived`. I am sorting and storing the first 6 objects with lowest `amount` value inside `arraySorted`. They are sorted on parameter named `amount`. There can be one or multiple objects with the same`lowest amount value`. I want to remove all the objects with the lowest `amount` value and store them in `arrayLowest`. It can be a single object or multiple if they all have same lowest amount. Rest I want to store in `arrayHigher`. How can I achieve it in typescript.

```
this.arrayRevceived.sort(function (a,b)) {
    return a.amount - b.amount;
  }
    this.arraySorted = arrayReceived.splice(0,6);
 }
// it is working till here, the problem starts here
 for(let i =0; i < this.arraySorted.length; i ++) {
   if (this.arraySorted[0].amount === this.arraySorted[i].amount){
    this.arrayLowest.push(this.arraySorted[i]);
   } else {
    this.arrayHighest.push(this.arraySorted[i]);
  }
 }
```

I am giving a for loop to match with the index[0] because as it is a sorted array, it will have the lowest value at index[0]. If it matches with next object values it will push that element into arrayLowest else into arrayHighest. But it is not working. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Just fyi, if(this.arraySorted[0].amount = this.arraySorted[i].amount) here inside if statement you are not comparing, its assignment.

Comment: Thank you. That was a typo. I have corrected it

Comment: @Bitly So lets say the sorted array has amout of `10, 20, 10 ,40, 50, 60` in that case arrayLowest will have two elements `10, 10` and arrayHighest should have the rest `20, 40, 50, 60` correct?

Comment: that is correct @KamranKhatti also, once I have arrayLowest and arrayHighest I want to display the data in HTML by binding. As of now I have logic for single array only. But how would I be able to implement the same logic on 2 arrays?

Comment: @Bitly submitted a fix can you check that out, also for binding in template can you please update your question and add template view how you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution as to filter out lowest and heighest value array.

```
let arr = [
  { amount: 50, id: 5 },
  { amount: 30, id: 4 },
  { amount: 10, id: 2 },
  { amount: 70, id: 7 },
  { amount: 60, id: 6 },
  { amount: 10, id: 1 },
  { amount: 20, id: 3 },
]

arr.sort((a, b) => a.amount - b.amount);
arr = arr.splice(0, 6);

const lowestValues = [];
const heighestValues = [];

arr.map((val) => arr[0].amount === val.amount ? lowestValues.push(val) : heighestValues.push(val));

console.log(lowestValues);
console.log(heighestValues);
```

Stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rqvxjv)